# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when initializing a 2dimensional array of objectts

Tags: java, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I have a very simple question but i can't figure out why I'm having this exception. I'm trying to create a 2-dimensional Array of objects for a sudoku puzzle, but when I'm initializing i'm getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Please help, I've read similar questions and it should be working!

Here I'm declaring the grid(2-dimensional array of objects used and constructor):

```
    public class Sudoku extends javax.swing.JFrame {
        private int lines;
        Cell[][] grid;

    public Sudoku() {
    initComponents();
    grid = new Cell[lines][lines];
```

So when i'm cliking a button to set the lines(size length) as shown below

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    lines=10;
    makeGrid(lines);
}
```

I'm getting the exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at Sudoku.makeGrid(Sudoku.java:146)

    public void makeGrid(int size) {

          for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
                for(int j=0;j<size;j++)    {
    146:                grid[i][j] = new Cell();
                }
          }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move your grid initialization into the make grid method since in the constructor the member `lines` is still not initialized with your desired value (default value of int is 0 so you get an empty array and you try to access it afterwards with bigger unallocated bounds)

```
public void makeGrid(int size) {
      this.lines = size; // If you do not need lines anywhere else then it is redundant
      grid = new Cell[size][size];
      for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<size;j++)    {
              grid[i][j] = new Cell();
            }
      }
```

Comment: In your example, lines has not been initialized either.

Comment: @ChristianKullmann actually if you will look again he is initializing it right before the call to makeGrid, BUT this is still should be moved to the makeGrid method

Comment: That is actually an edit. So my comment does not make any sense anymore :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the default value for an `int` is 0.

So when you create your `Sudoku` object, `grid = new Cell[lines][lines];` is equivalent to `grid = new Cell[0][0];`

Either change your `makeGrid` method or provide a size in your constructor.

```
public void makeGrid(int size) {
     this.lines = size;
     grid = new Cell[size][size];
     for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
          for(int j=0;j<size;j++){
              grid[i][j] = new Cell();
          }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`grid = new Cell[lines][lines];` creates an array of size `[0][0]` because `lines` is still `0` when that statement is run.

Whavetever changes you make to `lines` later on won't affect the array size, which will remain `[0][0]`...

Simpler example:

```
int size = 0;
Object[] array = new Object[size];
size = 1;
System.out.println(array.length); //prints 0, not 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! i didn't have this problem with C++. So the solution is to remove the creation of the array from the constructor and add it to the method?

Comment: That is one solution.

Comment: Can you recomend another one?

Comment: lines seems to always be 10, so you could also simply initialise it from the beginning: `private final int lines = 10;`

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `lines` before creation of array. Now you creating array with 0x0 dimensions, because `lines` is 0 be default.

```
lines = 10; // Add this line   
grid = new Cell[lines][lines];
```

Comment: I don't want the lines value fixed from the beggining that's why I'm having an action listener to a button to get the desired size. Thank you for your answer though!